Hall algebra of constructible functions of affine quiver?
I have read in "Quiver Representations and Quiver Varieties" by Kirillov that Hall algebra of constructible functions are defined only for Dynkin quivers because they are of finite type. So is there any Hall algebra of constructible functions of affine Dynkin quiver? If there exist such definition, could you point to me the right paper, thanks.
